# How to apply the same rotation between two vectors on world space.

Tags: rotations, quaternions, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Let's say that I have two vectors around a unit sphere, like the black vectors in the figure. I would like to apply *the same rotation* on another vector that is always [1, 0, 0] (blue one in the figure).
[image]
I already got quite a lot of code for doing that, however it's not perfectly. working.
It seems to work when the distance between the two vector is <45 degree, for example:
[image]
which looks ok.
However, with another pair of vectors, I get:
[image]
[image]

Which is wrong. **Why do I think it's wrong? I would think that applying the rotation between the two black vectors to the blue vector would result in a new rotation that is on the same latitude. However, this is clearly not the case**

This is the code I am using. Sorry for the length, but most of it it's used for plotting:
(you need the pyquaternion library: http://kieranwynn.github.io/pyquaternion/ )

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from pyquaternion import Quaternion
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
# draw sphere
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
x = np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color=[1, 0, 0, 0.2])

# draw a point
ax.scatter([0], [0], [0], color="g", s=100)

# draw a vector
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d


class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0, 0), (0, 0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

def norm_v(v):
    return v / np.linalg.norm(v)

def add_norm_vector(u, col="k", norm=True):
    if norm:
        u = norm_v(u)
    vh = Arrow3D([0, u[0]], [0, u[1]], [0, u[2]], mutation_scale=20,
            lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color=col)
    ax.add_artist(vh)
    return vh

def rotation_v_respect_to_u(v, u):
    rot = Quaternion(axis=np.cross(v, u), angle=np.arccos(np.dot(u, v))).normalised
    vv = rot.rotate([1, 0, 0])
    return vv

## THIS ONE IS CORRECT
a=[0, 1, 0]
b = [-0.671868,  2.399499  , -0.04294401]

distance = rotation_v_respect_to_u(a, b)
add_norm_vector([1, 0, 0], 'b')

add_norm_vector(a)
add_norm_vector(b)
add_norm_vector(distance, 'r')

## THIS ONE IS NOT CORRECT!
a=[0, 1, 0]
b = [-3.7956853 , -3.90564173, -1.713661]

distance = rotation_v_respect_to_u(a, b)
add_norm_vector([1, 0, 0], 'b')

add_norm_vector(a)
add_norm_vector(b)
add_norm_vector(distance, 'r')
```

The important bit is in the function `rotation_v_respect_to_u`. The formula is taken from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another

Comment: Without looking at your code: Why do you think that "it maps a vector $A$ to vector $B$" describes a **single** (unique) rotation? There are infinitely many such rotations. Either precompose it with a rotation using $A$ as an axis ord postcompose it with a rotation having $B$ as an axis. Anyway, to calculate what that rotation does to some third vector $C$, you need to describe it fully.

Comment: Actually, you didn't say how you defined the rotation. Sorry about jumping the gun a bit. Which rotation do you want to apply to the blue vector. How is that rotation specified (axes+ angle)?

Comment: I am not sure I know how to express it properly in terms of axes + angle (this is totally out of my comfort zone!) so I'll express it in a different way. I have two vectors, a and b. I want to take the rotation from a to b and apply it to a "forward" vector [1, 0, 0] on an horizontal plane.  Two examples of what I want here: https://ibb.co/vxGcKtb 
Is this clear enough? Or is the problem ill defined?

Comment: re-reading your first comment, I think I want to define A as an axis. Also - I am not just looking for a solution in python - a mathematical solution should be enough for me to figure it out!

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *the rotation between two black vectors*. I suspect that this may be the root cause of the problem. For example, a rotation preserves the latitudes if and only if the rotation is about the $z$-axis (which is how the Earth rotates after all).

Comment: Given two vectors $\bf a$ and $\bf b$, there are *infinitely many* rotations which send $\bf a$ to $\bf b$. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to simply say "*the*" rotation from $\bf a$ to $\bf b$. There is, of course, one rotation around an axis perpendicular to $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ which rotates by the angle between $\bf a$ and $\bf b$, is that what you mean? (Well, technically there are two, depending on if you want to go from $\bf a$ to $\bf b$ or $\bf b$ to $\bf a$.)

Comment: Judging from the drawings in your link you seem to cling to mistaken beliefs about how 3D-rotations work. For example, if $R$ is the rotation about an axis $\vec{a}$ by an angle $\theta$, it does not follow that the angle between $\vec{b}$ and $R(\vec{b})$ would be equal to $\theta$ for all vectors $\vec{b}$. Think about the Earth again. If you rotate the Earth by $\theta$ about its axis, the vector pointing towards the North pole from the center does not change at all.

Comment: (cont'd) The vectors pointing towards a location at  latitude $89$ degrees barely move. Only if $\vec{b}$ points towards the equator will you have angle $\theta$ between $\vec{b}$ and $R(\vec{b})$.

Comment: thanks, I think I am getting it now. I did manage to find a way to get exactly what I want. This is by estimating (`scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vector`) the rotation to optimally align [1, 0, 0] and one of the black vectors, and then apply this same rotation to the other vector. Some times it warns me that the rotation is not unique, and I just discard that vector. I would like to better understand what was my mistake in explaining this question. I am pretty sure that a better formulated question would have resulted in an answer in this community.

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand why the `align_vector` works and my original method didn't. My original method consisted in getting the quaternion to rotate one of the black vector to another along the axis resulting in their cross product. Then I applied this quaternion to [1, 0, 0]. For some reason, this method didn't work. But it seems pretty much equivalent to the other one I am using. Maybe a different optimization algorithm?